# jQuery Full Screen Div Slider With ScrollTo

Tags: jquery, slider, scrollto

I have a site who's navigation uses scrollTo to go to a selected slide. The slides are set via jQuery to be 100% of the window height and width. AFTER I use scrollTo, and THEN resize the window, the slide position is incorrect.

**My example can be viewed here:**
http://bit.ly/yRi72B

Click "Next", then resize the window to be larger and smaller and you will see what I mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set a variable the div you've just scrolled to
e.g.

```
$("div#logo").click ( function () {
    $("div#wrapper").scrollTo( "div#about", 1000);
    currentslide = "div#about";
});
```

then in your window resize event call

```
$("div#wrapper").scrollTo( currentslide, 0);
```

Comment: This _would_ work -- however executing scrollTo on every resize is _incredibly_ slow. On the right track though.

Comment: Whoops. Never mind. Forgot to make scrollTo have 0 animation time. Dur. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Use `$(window).resize()` to catch window resizing events and set your slide's width and height to 100% again.

Answer (score 0):

You can declare and initialize a variable current = "div#home"; then on your resizing function call your scroll function at the end.. $("div#wrapper").scrollTo( currentslide, 0);

and in your click function set current = "div#home" or "div#about"..

This work for me..

Good luck!